# What NEC code limits circuit breaker selection?

Tags: nec

I'm looking for a citation of the section of code that states more or less "You may only use breakers in a breaker panel that said panel lists as approved for use therein.".

What is the section number and actual verbiage as of the 2014 NEC?

Comment: I'm not asking for restrictions based on amperage, wire size, etc.   What rule makes it irrelevant if "a breaker fits"; Requiring instead that its suitable compatibility be explicitly listed by the manufacturer.

Comment: Is this a hypothetical or do you have a specific breaker which you would like to install in a certain panel, but that breaker is not listed for that panel?

Comment: What do you mean by "fits"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **110.2 Approval.** The conductors and equipment required or permitted by this Code shall be acceptable only if approved.
>
> **110.3￼(B) Installation and Use.** Listed or labeled equipment shall be installed and used in accordance with any instructions included in the listing or labeling.

Sometimes it's the basic stuff that's easiest to overlook.

Comment: I don't think this cite answers the question re: UL classified breakers, though

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel that's a tough one because the OEM presumably isn't thrilled that a competitor makes breakers for their panel.  I would rely on the principle of antecedance: your 1980s panel does not list *any* AFCI breakers, and so does that mean you can't put an AFCI in an 80s panel? No, since the breaker is obviously newer, the breaker being listed for the panel will suffice.  AKA the listings don't need to be *mutual*.